# Using proj string in java code?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, ogr, java

I want to do projection from UTM/oblique mercator CRS to WGS84. And I know the solution to use a proj.4 string in commandline like`+proj=omerc +lat_0=51.4 +lonc=7 +alpha=-10 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +gamma=0 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`

However, I wonder if there is a way to do such transformation using plain code. I have configured the gdal jar for my eclipse and want to use the java bindings to do such transformation. From the OGR projection tutorial,I know how to define a Geographic Coordinate System and projected Coordinate Sytem with OGRSpatialReference class. I know how to define a transformation using OGRCoordinateTransformation class. But the only thing missing there is the possibility to customize my source UTM. I don't know how to set the lon,lat of my orgin point. I also don't know how to set the oblique angle. There seems to be no such pre-built method in the classes.

Anyone can give me some hints?

Comment: The projection is not UTM (which stands for Universal Transverse Mercator), but solely oblique mercator. The lat_0 and lonc are the coordinates of your local CRS origin. You have to explore that with a GPS or from other maps. The angle you have to calculate from the coordinates of two known points on your local X-axis.

Comment: @AndreJoost yeah, I know what u mean. But now I can't even set a sample value lat/lon for my local CRS in plain java or C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use proj.4 java bindings like [GeoAPI](http://www.geoapi.org/geoapi-proj4/) and [Proj4j](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4j/). If you are familar with threads, process programming and piped streaming you can use a [direct OS call](http://tech.enekochan.com/2013/02/21/run-a-command-from-a-java-application-dealing-properly-with-stdin-stdout-and-stderr/) whith your common proj.4 params.

Proj4j looks like this and [have a look in Martin Davis unit test repository](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4j/browser/trunk/src/test/java/org/osgeo/proj4j/) :

```java
package org.osgeo.proj4j;

import junit.textui.TestRunner;

/**
 * Tests from the PROJ4 testvarious file.
 * 
 * @author Martin Davis
 *
 */
public class Proj4VariousTest extends BaseCoordinateTransformTest
{ 
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    TestRunner.run(Proj4VariousTest.class);
  }

  public Proj4VariousTest(String name) { super(name); }

  public void testRawEllipse()
  {
    checkTransform(
        "+proj=latlong +ellps=clrk66", p("79d58'00.000W 37d02'00.000N"), 
        "+proj=latlong +ellps=bessel", p("79d58'W 37d2'N"), 0.01 );
    checkTransform(
        "+proj=latlong +ellps=clrk66", p("79d58'00.000\"W 36d58'00.000\"N"), 
        "+proj=latlong +ellps=bessel", p("79d58'W 36d58'N"), 0.01 );
  }

  public void testNAD27toRawEllipse()
  {
    checkTransform(
        "+proj=latlong +datum=NAD27", p("79d00'00.000\"W 35d00'00.000\"N"), 
        "+proj=latlong +ellps=bessel", p("79dW 35dN"), 0.01 );
  }

  public void test3ParamApproxSameEllipsoid()
  {
    checkTransform(
        "+proj=latlong +ellps=bessel +towgs84=5,0,0", p("0d00'00.000W 0d00'00.000N"), 
        "+proj=latlong +ellps=bessel +towgs84=1,0,0", p("0dE  0dN 4.000"), 1e-5 );
    checkTransform(
        "+proj=latlong +ellps=bessel +towgs84=5,0,0", p("79d00'00.000W 45d00'00.000N 0.0"), 
        "+proj=latlong +ellps=bessel +towgs84=1,0,0", p("78d59'59.821W  44d59'59.983N 0.540"), 1e-5 );
  }
  public void test3ParamToRawSameEllipsoid()
  {
    checkTransform(
        "+proj=latlong +ellps=bessel +towgs84=5,0,0", p("0d00'00.000W 0d00'00.000N"), 
        "+proj=latlong +ellps=bessel", p("0dE  0dN 4.000"), 1e-5 );
  }

  public void FAIL_test3ParamToRawSameEllipsoid2()
  {
    // fails - not sure why, possibly missing towgs not handled in same way as PROJ4?
    checkTransform(
        "+proj=latlong +ellps=bessel +towgs84=5,0,0", p("79d00'00.000W 45d00'00.000N 0.0"), 
        "+proj=latlong +ellps=bessel", p("79dW  45dN 0.000"), 1e-5 );
  }

  public void testStere()
  {
    checkTransform(
        "+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84", p("105 40"), 
        "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=70 +datum=WGS84", p("5577808.93 1494569.40 0.00"), 1e-2 );
  }
  public void testStereWithout_lat_ts()
  {
    checkTransform(
        "+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84", p("20 45"), 
        "+proj=stere +lat_0=40 +lon_0=10  +datum=WGS84", p("789468.08 602385.33 0.00"), 1e-2 );
  }
  public void testSTS()
  {
    checkTransform(
        "+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84", p("4.897000 52.371000"), 
        "+proj=kav5 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m", p("383646.09  5997047.89"), 1e-2 );
    checkTransform(
        "+proj=kav5 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m", p("383646.088858 5997047.888175"),
        "+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84", p("4d53'49.2E  52d22'15.6N"), 
        1e-5 );
  }
  // disabled - gamma param not implemented
  public void XXX_testRSOBorneo()
  {
    checkTransform(
        "+proj=latlong +a=6377298.556 +rf=300.8017", p("116d2'11.12630 5d54'19.90183"), 
        "+proj=omerc +a=6377298.556 +rf=300.8017 +lat_0=4 +lonc=115 +alpha=53d18'56.9537 +gamma=53d7'48.3685  +k_0=0.99984 +x_0=590476.87 +y_0=442857.65", 
        p("704570.40  653979.68"), 1e-2 );
  }
  public void FAIL_testPconic()
  {
    checkTransform(
        "+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84", p("-70.4 -23.65"), 
        "+proj=pconic  +units=m +lat_1=20n +lat_2=60n +lon_0=60W +datum=WGS84", p("-2240096.40  -6940342.15"),
        1e-2 );
    // Known failure case
    checkTransform(
        "+proj=pconic  +units=m +lat_1=20n +lat_2=60n +lon_0=60W +datum=WGS84", p("-2240096.40  -6940342.15"),
        "+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84", p("-70.4 -23.65"), 
        1e-2 );
  }

}
```